# Serving the static content of a Firebase app

Tags: firebase

From what I can infer from the Firebase docs, it seems that 
a server is required to serve the static content (the html 
and javascript), so you need to have a hosted machine and a
static content server up and running somewhere, or some service
to host a static site.

Is that correct ?

Throughout the Firebase site they repeatedly mention the 
"no server needed" concept, so I was initially thinking
that Firebase did provide a mean to serve static content,
but there is no mention of it in the docs.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: @hiattp already answered beautifully. I would indeed read the "no server needed" as "no application server needed".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Firebase does offer static hosting now, see link in answer below.

---

Firebase isn't a replacement for servers in every situation, but in some cases you can use Firebase *instead* of a server, or reduce server code you would otherwise have to write and maintain.

<s>If you want to serve static HTML/CSS/JS to browsers great, but Firebase won't do it for you (you would at least need to jumpstart it). In this scenario you could serve assets on any cheap hosting site, but then make those traditionally static assets data-driven via Firebase without writing any server-side code.</s>

The docs refer to "no server needed" scenarios because traditional web applications aren't the only use-case. You could build entire real-time mobile applications or browser extensions without hosting or serving anything yourself.

Comment: I use a humble web-hosting company for my static files. £3 a month. Job done.

Comment: Firebase now offers hosting of static files

Answer (score 3):

Firebase now offers hosting (in Beta) for your static asset files, so they are even more a "one stop shop".

https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting.html